# how to get totall number of text nodes of HTML document?

Tags: php

Here is my code :

i want to get totall number of text node in HTML Document.

```
 // a new dom object
$dom = new domDocument;

// load the html into the object
$dom->loadHTMLFile('translated/test.html');

// discard white space
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$i = 0;

// get elements by tagname body
while ($bodynodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item($i)) {
    myFunc($bodynodes);
    $i++;
}

//var_dump($holder);

function myFunc($node) {
    static $i;
    if (!isset($i)) {
        $i = 0;
    }
    if ($node->childNodes) {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $subNode):
            myFunc($subNode);
        endforeach;
    }else {

        if ($node->nodeType == 3 && trim($node->nodeValue) != ''):
            $i++;


        endif;
    }
    if ($node->lastChild):
        echo $i;
    endif;
}
```

But what i get is

```
Result ====>  1233
```

as there are only 3 text segment in my HTML document.

Comment: $node->type == 3 means only text node are allowed and also i have filter for blank node as well, anywayx i can apply more filters if needed but issue is that how can i get the count only once as returned value ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work to get the total:

```
$count = myFunc($dom->getElementsByTagName('body'));
echo "The document has $count text nodes\n";

function myFunc($node) {
    if ($node->childNodes) {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $subNode):
            $total+= myFunc($subNode);
        endforeach;
        return $total;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($node->nodeType == 3 && trim($node->nodeValue) != '') {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is call `myFunc` if the node has children treating those children as new trees and returning the number of text nodes toting up the sum. Otherwise it returns 1 or 0 depending on the node type and its value.

Comment: it is returning this "The document has 0 text nodes"